# Hostapd on raspberrypi nl80211 error

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, hostapd, access-point

I'm trying to make my raspberry pi (1) run as an access point, I used hostapd and dhcpd but I get this error message

> "nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or
>   connect commands"

when starting hostapd. The dongle I use uses the **RTL8188CUS** chipset. The same dongle with the same commands and configuration files work flawlessly on my raspberry pi 3. How can I make it work with my raspberry pi (1)?

Comment: To be clear (because this entered the "closed because problem went away" queue), you still have this problem on the RPI (1)?

Comment: yeah the problem occurs only on my raspberry pi 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the kernel fixed the issue with nl80211 hostapd now works perfectly.

i also managed to find a modified [binary](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1663660/hostapd/hostapd.zip) that made hostapd work with the old kernel version using the **rtl871xdrv** driver for **RTL8188CUS** compatible chipsets. install hostapd and replace the modified version.

```
#save original 
sudo mv /usr/sbin/hostapd /usr/sbin/hostapd.bak
#move modified version
sudo mv hostapd /usr/sbin/hostapd
sudo chown root.root /usr/sbin/hostapd
sudo chmod 755 /usr/sbin/hostapd
```